# jQuery DatePicker: Limit the date typed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've a big problem. I'm using a input with a datepicker.
The datepicker is set to select only date in the calendar witch are after the current day. But the user can write any date in the input.

There is a way to limit that with the DatePicker control or I've to create this myself?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see a built in tool, but parseDate utility included with the plugin should make implementing this pretty easy. The real question is, `what should happen if they enter an invalid date?`

Answer (score 0):

The minDate and maxDate methods also count for the input String. Since it is never 100% reliable (focus-changes/non-js) and better style, you should use some kind of validation before accepting the date nevertheless.

more info: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: Sadly not, you can still type any date outside the `minDate` or `maxDate` range

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the keystroke so everytime they input a number, it get backspaced.

http://jsfiddle.net/ehkzG/

Comment: My problem is: if the minDate is set to 09/15/2011, users can write 09/13/2011 in the field :(

Comment: yeah, check my example, if they type a number it will get backspaced.